# Turn on gzip compression for grizzly under JerseyTest

Tags: junit, gzip, jersey, grizzly

I have jersey implementation of web service. The response per requirements must be gzip-ed.

Client side contains following bootstrap code to switch gzip on:

```
Client retval = Client.create();
retval.addFilter(
    new com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter());
```

For Tomcat web.xml gzip is configured as follow

```
 <servlet>
  <display-name>JAX-RS REST Servlet</display-name>
  <servlet-name>JAX-RS REST Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
      com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
  </servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter</param-value>
  </init-param>
```

And everything works fine!

But I need write unit test that invokes my service.  I'm using JerseyTest as base and in practice way it was shown that grizzly is not correctly handles gzip without explicit declaration. I have found code snippet how to switch it on [similar problem](http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/GZipContentEncodingFilter-Sample-td4920049.html), but I have no idea how to combine it with JerseyTest.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample test case if you're using the jersey test Framwork:

```
@Test
public void testGet(){    

    WebResource webResource = resource();

    ClientResponse result = webResource
        .path("pathToResource")
        .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip")
        .head();

    assertEquals(
       "response header must contain gzip encoding",
       "[gzip]",
       result.getHeaders().get("Content-Encoding").toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AS the client API changed in the current Jersey versions, this is a sample test which works with Jersey 2.6:

```
public class WebServicesCompressionTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Path("/")
    public static class HelloResource {

        @GET
        public String getHello() {
            return "Hello World!";
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        enable(TestProperties.LOG_TRAFFIC);
        return new ResourceConfig(
                HelloResource.class,
                EncodingFilter.class,
                GZipEncoder.class,
                DeflateEncoder.class
        );
    }

    @Test
    public void testGzip() {
        Response response = target().request().acceptEncoding("gzip").get(Response.class);

        assertThat(response.getStatus(), is(200));
        assertThat(response.getHeaderString("Content-encoding"), is("gzip"));
    }
}
```